# how to print all dates inside cells from 1 to totalDays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calendar and I want to print date from 1 to 30 or 31 depends on the month, And I have that total days in variable `totalDays`, I have created `tr` and `td`'s in nested loops but not sure how to print value inside each `td` from 1 to 30.

```
var date = new Date('11/13/2016');

        var totalDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

        var daysArr = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'];

        totalDays = totalDays.getDate();        

        var table = document.createElement('table');   


        for (var i = 0; i <= 5+1; i++) {

            var tr = table.insertRow(i);

            for(var ii = 0; ii <= 7-1; ii++){
                var td = tr.insertCell(ii);
                td.innerHTML = (ii);


            }
        }

        console.log(table);
```

Comment: two for loop length are same .just remove one loop

Answer (score 0):

to fill the days, you can try this one:

```js
var date = new Date('11/13/2016'),
  totalDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0),
  // i changed the order to synchronize with getDay() in js => Sun = 0
  daysArr = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
  table = document.createElement('table'),
  row = 0,
  d = 1,
  h = new Date(date.setDate(1));

totalDays = totalDays.getDate();
h = h.getDay();

while (d <= totalDays + daysArr.length) {
  var tr = table.insertRow(row);
  for (var ii = 0; ii < daysArr.length; ii++) {
    if (d > totalDays + daysArr.length) {
      break;
    }
    var td = tr.insertCell(ii);
    if (d <= daysArr.length) {
      //filling the Header for calendar
      td.innerHTML = daysArr[h];
      d++;
      if (h >= daysArr.length - 1) {
        h = 0;
      } else {
        h++
      }
    } else {
      //filling the dates
      td.innerHTML = d++ - daysArr.length;
    }
  }
  row++;
}


document.body.appendChild(table);
console.log('Total Days this month:', totalDays);
```

Of course it has not finish yet for your calendar project. but hope this help